# Why does an Excel VSTO addin run slower on a higher spec machine? (part II)

Tags: excel, performance, vsto

According to the above question we have noticed that the difference in the performance related to the below code:

```
Dim myRange As xli.Range = TryCast(zWorksheet.Range(zWorksheet.Cells(y1, x1), zWorksheet.Cells(y1, x1)), xli.Range)
```

where xli:

```
Imports xli = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and edit your question accordingly. Specifically your question should be complete and not depend on another question (though a link for reference is a good thing).

Comment: I try  completely remove excel and then reinstall it  but does not change the situation !

Comment: A try to change the slower computer performance parameters (windows 7) does not make any difference !